# Issue with adding items to JComboBox in Java

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am a beginner to Java and I have a JComboBox control already on my screen.

In my code I am trying to read data from a file and populate the combo box with it.

I have gone through the documentation and examples from searching here and tried below two methods to perform this action:

I tried to:

```
jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
jComboBox1.addItem("test string");
```

and then I tried to do this:

```
jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
            jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "test", "string" }));
```

I get no errors when I run the program, but nothing happens to the Combo Box data and it just contains the default values of Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4.

Can someone help me with what I am missing?

Edited - Here is the code for the procedure. This procedure is called from the public static void main(String args[]) procedure which seems to run when the program starts. The stuff being printed to the System output shows up so I know the code block is running, and there are no errors generated.

2nd Edit - I thought the issue was with combobox, but I tried changing label or text field value but they don't work either. I have updated code to show the procedure about it where I am able to update the label and text field, but in the procedure below it doesn't work. I must not be referring to the controls properly for some reason in the procedure I created compared to the one that was system generated?

3rd Edit - Ok more testing and it is the way I am calling the second procedure is where the issue is. If I run the second procedure from the first, everything works fine. I did below to run the procedure when JFrame starts and that is where the issue is. Trying to figure out how to fix that now.

```
NewJFrame test = new NewJFrame();
test.LoadCmbData();


private void cmdStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (cmdStart.getText()=="Start Game")
        {
            //randVar.nextInt();
            //strWord=strWords[Integer.valueOf(cmbRnd.getSelectedItem().toString())];
            txtOutput.setText("");
            txtOutput.setEnabled(true);
            txtInput.setEnabled(true);
            cmdInput.setEnabled(true);
            cmdStart.setText("End Game");
            lblStatus.setText("Enter your first guess and click 'Check'");
            intTries=0;
            //jComboBox1.addItem("test string");
            //lblStatus.setText("Click 'Start Game' button to begin");
        }
        else
        {
            cmdStart.setText("Start Game");
            txtInput.setText("");
            txtInput.setEnabled(false);
            cmdInput.setEnabled(false);
            //txtOutput.setText("");
            txtOutput.setEnabled(false);
            lblStatus.setText("Click 'Start Game' button to begin");

        }
    }                                        


    public void LoadCmbData() 
    {
         Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);

         // Load word choices from file

         try 
            {
                File readfile = new File(s + "\\words.txt");
                ArrayList linedata = readfile.OpenFile();
                System.out.println("ArrayList populated");

//                NewJFrame test = new NewJFrame();
//                test.cmbRnd.removeAllItems();
//                test.cmbRnd.addItem("test");
//                test.cmbRnd.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "test", "string", "test", "string", "one" }));
//                //test.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(linedata.toArray()));
//                test.cmbRnd.updateUI();
//                test.cmbRnd.revalidate();
//                test.cmbRnd.repaint();

               lblStatus.setText("test ");

                txtInput.setEnabled(true);
                txtInput.setText("test");

                jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
                jComboBox1.addItem("test string");
                jComboBox1.updateUI();
                jComboBox1.revalidate();
                jComboBox1.repaint();


                //NewJFrame test = new NewJFrame();
                       // test.repaint();
                       // test.revalidate();



                //jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
                //jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "test", "string" }));
                //jComboBox1.updateUI();
                //jComboBox1.revalidate();


            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use the `updateUI()` method (or `revalidate()` or something like this)?

Comment: No I did not. Let me look up the documentation and try it. I'll report back shortly. Thanks!

Comment: ok I tried the following seperately, but neither worked. Should I be calling those methods in a different way than below?
jComboBox1.updateUI();
jComboBox1.revalidate();

Comment: You are sure using the right variablename? In your code you use once  `JComboBox1` and then `jComboBox1`

Comment: sorry, I typed the first one manually and accidently held shift for the J...the second one i copied and pasted since it was harder to type from memory being new :) I will edit it.

Comment: Yep that's how you use these methods...You have called these methods after you have changed the comboBox don't you?

Comment: Maybe some more code lines would help us, to help you ..

Comment: Joel, I edited the original post to contain the code for that procedure. Thanks.

Comment: @KahnMun Maybe try `jComboBox1.repaint();` or `yourPanel.repaint();`/`yourPanel.revalidate();`

Comment: Dan, the jComboBox1.repaint(); didn't work either. I don't have a panel in the form. How do I point to the main JFrame form itself to try it on there?

Comment: Ok i must be doing something wrong across the board. I assumed the issue was with combobox, but when I try to update text for a label or textfield they don't work either. They both work in my other procedures.

I've updated my code to show the other procedure where it works. Should I be referring to the controls in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. Being the total newbie that I am, I was calling that procedure from the "public static void main(String args[])" procedure thinking that is where the loading code goes since it worked when I did some System.out messages.

After backtracking my issue and figuring out above was cause, I now know to put the procedure in the "Constructor" method which I now have learnt about.

I still don't know why it doesn't work from the other location since it obviously runs the procedure, just doesn't update controls. If someone is willing to explain that to me that would be helpful.

Thanks!